# Validation of config rejected with errors. Config is NOT set

Tags: angular, authentication, asp.net-identity

I started working on this project about a year ago.
Suddenly I got the following error[image]

This is an angular/Identity Server/ Web Api Implementation.
For some strange reason the identity server doesnt seem to be receiving the configuration information it needs to validate the client app.
Right at the app launch it complains " The authority URL MUST be provided in the configuration! Validation of config rejected with errors. Config is NOT set"

Below is the code in my app.module where the configuration is supposed to be set

```
export const httpLoaderFactory = (httpClient: HttpClient) => {
  const config$ = httpClient.get<any>(`${window.location.origin}/api/ClientAppSettings`)
    .pipe(
      map((customConfig: any) => {
        return {
          stsServer: customConfig.stsServer,
          redirectUrl: customConfig.redirect_url,
          clientId: customConfig.client_id,
          responseType: customConfig.response_type,
          scope: customConfig.scope,
          postLogoutRedirectUri: customConfig.post_logout_redirect_uri,
          startCheckSession: customConfig.start_checksession,
          silentRenew: customConfig.silent_renew,
          silentRenewUrl: customConfig.redirect_url + '/silent-renew.html',
          postLoginRoute: customConfig.startup_route,
          forbiddenRoute: customConfig.forbidden_route,
          unauthorizedRoute: customConfig.unauthorized_route,
          logLevel: 0, // LogLevel.logLevel or customConfig.logLevel
          maxIdTokenIatOffsetAllowedInSeconds: customConfig.max_id_token_iat_offset_allowed_in_seconds,
          historyCleanupOff: true,
          // autoUserInfo: false,
        };
      })
    )
  //.toPromise();

  return new StsConfigHttpLoader(config$);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're using the [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client) and have updated to V12 from a lower version (V11 and earlier) without following the correct migration path.

For example V11 uses `stsServer:` for it's `authority URL` (as your example has) but V12 changed it to `authority:`.

Follow the migration instructions on the official [`Angular Auth OIDC Client Docs` site](https://nice-hill-002425310.azurestaticapps.net/docs/migrations/v11-to-v12) for each version change. That is for V11-V12 but it has all the others on that page as well.